# Excel adding IFERROR to progress statement (conditional formatting)

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW5jS.png)For example I have a start date cell and an end date cell. I also have a conditional format statement that will take these two cells and calculate the progress in % of how complete my project is.

For example:

```
Bathroom Renovation: 
Start 11/7/2022
Finish: 11/9/2022
Progress 33%
```

Here is my excel code to calculate this:

```
=MIN(1, (DATEDIF(E11,TODAY(),"d")+1)/(DATEDIF(E11,F11,"d")+1))
```

I need to add an IFERROR (or some condition like) so that when there is no start or end date is says "Not Started" for example.

I have tried this:

```
=IFERROR((DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"d")+1)/(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"d")+1),"Not start").
```

That problem that I've run into with this is I am trying to cap the percentage at 100%, and the code statement I started with does that. When I enter this string of code, it works, however when a project is complete it will say 150%, 450%, etc. I need it to also cap at 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `E15` is your start date and `F15` is your finish date, try:

`=IF(ISBLANK(E15),"Not start",IFERROR(MIN(1,(DATEDIF(E15,TODAY(),"d")+1)/(DATEDIF(E15,F15,"d")+1)),"Not start"))`

This will display the progress as not started if there is no start date.

Answer (score 0):

The `=MIN(1,"other code")` part is capping the value at 100% in the first example and it is missing from the second. try:

```
=IFERROR(MIN(1,(DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"d")+1)/(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"d")+1)),"Not start")
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried that code and it partially worked. I inputted the following: =IFERROR(MIN(1,(DATEDIF(E15,TODAY(),"d")+1)/(DATEDIF(E15,F15,"d")+1)),"Not start")  This worked when I had a start date inputted but ideally I would like for the box to be empty and be able to have a finish date. (i.e Start date: (blank or -) and Finish (insert finish date), This above code only works if I enter a start date and have no finish date.